# How to delete duplicate text from a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I tried to delete the tect with the following command

```
sed -i -e 's/<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>//g' standalone.xml
```

But its showing me error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown option to `s'

Can someone guide what is the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first character after `s` is used as a separator. You chose `/`, so the correct command would be:

`s/search/replace/flags`

The problem is you have extra `/` in your `search` part:

```
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                                     ^
```

So sed parses it like this:

```
Search:   <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1<
Replace:  check-valid-connection-sql>
Flags:    /g
```

And `/` is not a correct flag.

Use a different separator to fix this:

```
s#<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>##g
```

Comment: You can also escape the '/' character with a backslash like '\/'.